# how does numpy implement the slice

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((3, 3))

y = x[:, 0]

y[1] = 2 # x[1,0] is changed

print(x)

z = x[0, :]

z[2] = 3 # x[0, 2] is changed

print(x)
```

How does the data stored and implemented?

If c(or fortran) is used, 2-dim array x[3][3]

z=x[0,:], return a pointer point to the address of x[0][0], then z[2] = 3 can change the value of x[0][2].

But how does y[1]=2 do? The address of x[0][0] x[1][0] x[2][0] is not continuous.

Does numpy use another variable to remember the next element?

Comment: https://ajcr.net/stride-guide-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

```
In [64]: x = np.zeros((3, 3))
In [65]: x
Out[65]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

Some useful information about `x`:

```
In [66]: x.__array_interface__
Out[66]: 
{'data': (1510169114000, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'shape': (3, 3),
 'version': 3}

In [67]: x.strides
Out[67]: (24, 8)
```

'data' is some sort of pointer to the c array that stores the 9 values of `x`.  It is accessed as 2d using the strides - step by 8 bytes to go from one column to the next, by 3*28 to go to the next row

`y` is `view`, an new array, but which shares memory with `x`:

```
In [68]: y = x[:, 0]    
In [69]: y
Out[69]: array([0., 0., 0.])

In [70]: y.__array_interface__
Out[70]: 
{'data': (1510169114000, False),         # same data as x
 'strides': (24,),                       # going down rows
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'shape': (3,),
 'version': 3}

In [71]: y.base
Out[71]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

Modifying a `y` element modifies the same one in `x`:

```
In [72]: y[1] = 2
In [73]: y
Out[73]: array([0., 2., 0.])

In [74]: x
Out[74]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

A view of a row:

```
In [75]: z = x[0, :]    
In [76]: z
Out[76]: array([0., 0., 0.])

In [77]: z.__array_interface__
Out[77]: 
{'data': (1510169114000, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'shape': (3,),
 'version': 3}

In [78]: z.strides
Out[78]: (8,)           # same column stride
```

Modifying a `z` element changes `y` also (if the overlap):

```
In [79]: z[0]=3
In [80]: y
Out[80]: array([3., 2., 0.])
```

This striding also makes reshaping fast - no data copies.  Also transpose is fast.

```
In [81]: xt = x.transpose()
In [82]: xt
Out[82]: 
array([[3., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
In [83]: xt.strides
Out[83]: (8, 24)        # same base, just switched strides
```

Comment: My only objection here is that OP has taken zero time to read through the numpy docs, or the link you posted, where all of this is explained quite clearly.